# Why does this Ajax ID selector return an array?

Tags: jquery

By definition, there can only be one control on a page with a given ID.

This statement set the value of a single control:

```
document.getElementById("ctl00_phPageContent_dtmVisitChinaFrom_txtSkipValidation").value = "1";
```

Why is the "[0]" necessary?

```
$("#ctl00_phPageContent_dtmVisitChinaFrom_txtSkipValidation")[0].value = "1";
```

Comment: Some HTML please? Could by 2 elements with same ID

Comment: jQuery always returns *array-like* objects, even when there is only a single result returned. And I think your example is missing a `#` for the element id; e.g. `$("#ctl00_phPageContent_dtmVisitChinaFrom_txtSkipValidation")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do this:

```
$("ctl00_phPageContent_dtmVisitChinaFrom_txtSkipValidation")[0]
```

Or

```
$("ctl00_phPageContent_dtmVisitChinaFrom_txtSkipValidation").get(0)
```

You are accessing actual DOM element which has `value` property available.

It isn't necessary if you use `val()` method of jQuery instead:

```
$("#ctl00_phPageContent_dtmVisitChinaFrom_txtSkipValidation").val('1')
```

---

So `[index]` part is necessary when you want to access native methods/properties of elements not otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

For consistency. Even though `id` nominally corresponds to a single element, other jQuery selectors may return multiple results. To keep things cool and predictable, all jQuery results end up in collections.

Answer (score 1):

The correct code is:

```
$("#ctl00_phPageContent_dtmVisitChinaFrom_txtSkipValidation").val() = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jQuery):

> A jQuery object contains a collection of Document Object Model (DOM) elements that have been created from an HTML string or selected from a document. Since jQuery methods often use CSS selectors to match elements from a document, the set of elements in a jQuery object is often called a set of "matched elements" or "selected elements".
>
> The jQuery object itself behaves much like an array; it has a length property and the elements in the object can be accessed by their numeric indices [0] to [length-1]. Note that a jQuery object is not actually a Javascript Array object, so it does not have all the methods of a true Array object such as join().

The most relevant part to your question is "*the set of elements in a jQuery object is often called **a set** of "matched elements" or "selected elements".*"

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where you got this code from, but according to my experience "[0]" is realy not needed at all. 
The thing that maces my curious in this codeline is what are you trying to do with the ".value =1". The "value" property in jQuery is operated by the function .val() - http://api.jquery.com/val/